# InProc in Session state

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is difference between below two codes.

**1st code.**

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

**2nd Code**

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

I know using inproc use web servers to store session and inproc is default mode for sessionstate mode then what is difference between above two code or both same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same.  The default value for the sessionState mode is "InProc".

In the first example you are explicitly setting the mode to "InProc".

In the second example, no mode is specified, hence the default "InProc" mode is used.

If you want to make absolutely sure that you are using "InProc" mode, explicitly stating so as in the first example can be good.  In the unlikely event that the default mode gets changed from InProc to something else, you'll still be using InProc :-)